# Ignoring files in project folder for Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

**How can you ignore files by Doxygen similarly as by Git's `.git/info/exclude`?**

Doxygen generates docs for me based on 3rd party codes such Email -component and of my Git -repo, which I do not want.
I need to keep the files where they are.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the EXCLUDE_PATTERNS tag in the configuration file:

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = */test/*
```

Taken from [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_excl_dir).

Comment: If you're using the Doxygen GUI frontend "Doxywizard" v. 1.8 (2015), this is under the Expert>Input tab.

Comment: What if the directory name has space? For example, if it is `test files`.