# How to include only some source files in Doxygen-generated documentation?

Tags: doxygen

In my project, I'd like to scan ***all*** source files for documentation, but only include in the generated documentation the full source code for ***some*** source files (example code, for example).

Currently I've set `SOURCE_BROWSER` and `VERBATIM_HEADERS` to `NO`, so no source files are included.

Is there some way I can provide a list of source files I'd like to include despite those settings?

Or, if I turn those options back on, is there some way I can provide a list of source files to exclude?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1354056

Comment: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude

Comment: @RobertHarvey: `EXCLUDE` and `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS`, if I understand correctly, both exclude the file altogether — the file is not scanned for documentation.  But I'm looking for a way to extract the documentation from a file, without including the full source of the file in the generated documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to only specify a specific list of files that need to be processed with `SOURCE_BROWSER` enabled.

You can however include examples, see [snippet](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsnippet), [example](http://www.doxygen.nl/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdexample), [dontinclude](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddontinclude), or [verbinclude](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbinclude) for various ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks; `\include` is what I needed, since it also highlights syntax and links to methods.